# Prove post-composition map is isomorphism.

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $f \colon X \to NC$ be a natural transformation. ($C$ a category and $N$ is nerve functor from Cat to sSet) Consider post-composition map $Hom(\wedge^n_1, X) \to Hom(\wedge^n_1, NC)$. Assume that the post composition map $Hom(\triangle^n, X) \to Hom(\triangle^n, NC)$ is bijective for $j < n$. Then show that $Hom(\wedge^n_1, X) \to Hom(\wedge^n_1, NC)$ is also bijective.

The problem comes from part of this proof: [image]

I get that the general idea is $\wedge^n_1$ is colimit of simplices of diemension less than $n$ and we can use this fact, but the details escape me. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Well, it's a colimit, so write it as a colimit. Then use the fact that $\textrm{Hom} (\varinjlim T, -) \cong \varprojlim \textrm{Hom} (T, -)$.

Comment: @ZhenLin right so we have map from lim Hom to lim Hon, I wasn't sure the details as to how prove that is isomorphism.

Comment: That is a general fact about limits and colimits, in any category.

Comment: @ZhenLin right the statement prove is if $Hom( \triangle^S, X) \to Hom(\triangle^S, Y)$ is iso for each $S$, the $lim Hom(\triangle^S, X) \to lim Hom(\triangle^S,Y)$ is also iso.

Comment: This, too, is a general fact about limits in any category...

Comment: @ZhenLin I guess it's just not clear how to prove this general fact but thanks!